# insertar - eliminar datos en tiempo real mostrados en una tabla dentro de una pagina en wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Saludos amigos espero me puedan ayudar con este problema, estoy haciendo un sistema de pedidos sencillo en wordpress y tengo algunos problemas para completar la tarea...

estoy trabajando con wordpress y elementor pro para el diseño web de este sistema de pedidos.

el sistema funciona de la siguiente forma... // este es un sistema simple de pedidos de productos

1.- El usuario pulsa el botón "nuevo pedido" y se despliega un popup con la lista de todos los productos
2.- la lista esta en una tabla que muestra Codigo, descripción, cantidad (aqui el usuario coloca el numero), precio y un signo mas (+) para agregar el producto... // esta parte me funciona bien
3.- una vez hecho el pedido se muestra una tabla con el resumen y el precio total con un icono de un pote de basura para eliminar el pedido que no desee... // aqui empieza mi dolor de cabeza..

necesito poder eliminar los productos instantaneamente y agregar los productos instantaneamente...

nota: este sistema lo tengo terminado en programación tradicional fuera de wordpress, y es funcional. Esto llevando el sistema a funcionar con la programación de wordpress...

es complicado explicar todo lo que he hecho pero mostraré mi codigo e imagenes de las fallas...

[image: tabla de resumen de pedidos vacia]
**tabla de resumen de pedidos vacia**

[image: tabla para añadir productos a la imagen anterior]
**tabla para añadir productos  que se van a mostrar en la primera imagen**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Productos añadidos (se repite toda la tabla cada vez que agrego uno o mas productos ej: si agrego 2 productos se añaden dos nuevas tablas la ya existente que tengo en la misma pagina de muestra en codigo completo (no el div)

- Estoy usando un [shortcode] que contiene el php de agregar pedidos. Esta tabla no muestra los productos agregados sino cuando refresco la pagina. El icono de pote de basura borra el pedido como lo requiero pero igual, tambien se muestra despues de agregar la pagina
- aparte del codigo anterior, coloque un div que me repite los resultados  // por eso se ven varios pedidos repetidos.
- El div tiene la particularidad de mostrar los productos y agregar en tiempo real los productos pero el pote de basura no funciona, al pulsarlo no manda ninguna acción a ninguna parte.

//muestro  a continuacion mis codigos...

```
function my_action_callback() {

      check_ajax_referer( 'my-special-string', 'security' );
      $pedidos = $_POST['data'];

      $session_id = get_current_user_id();         
      global $wpdb; // Este objeto global nos permite trabajar con la BD de WP 
      $wpdb->show_errors();  
      
      $table_tmp = 'em_tmp';
      if (isset($pedidos['id'])){
        $id = sanitize_text_field ($pedidos['id']);   
      }
      if (isset($pedidos['cantidad'])){
        $cantidad = sanitize_text_field ($pedidos['cantidad']) ; 
      }
      if (isset($pedidos['precio_venta'])){
        $precio_venta = sanitize_text_field ($pedidos['precio_venta']) ;
      }
     
      if (!empty($id) and !empty($cantidad) and !empty($precio_venta)) {

      $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix.'tmp', array('id_producto' => $id, 'cantidad_tmp' => $cantidad, 'precio_tmp' => $precio_venta,'session_id' => $session_id ));
      }       
      //echo ("$id, $cantidad, $precio_venta");
       if ( isset($_GET) ) {
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) { 
            $id_tmp = $_GET['data'];
            echo $id_temp;
            global $wpdb;     
            $wpdb->show_errors(); 
            $wpdb->delete( $wpdb->prefix.'tmp', array('id_tmp' => $id_tmp));                
        }
       }
                
      echo'
        <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>codigo_producto</th>
          <th>cantidad</th>
          <th>Descripción</th>
          <th><span class="d-flex justify-content-end">Precio Unitario</span></th>
          <th><span class="d-flex justify-content-end">Precio Total</span></th>
          <th>Eliminar</th>
        </tr>';

      $sumador_total=0;

      global $wpdb;
      $wpdb->show_errors(); 
      $table_productos = $wpdb->prefix .'productos'; // nombre de la tabla 
      $table_tmp = $wpdb->prefix . 'tmp'; // nombre de la tabla 
      $prod = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_productos p, $table_tmp t where p.id_producto = t.id_producto and t.session_id='".$session_id."'");
      foreach ($prod as $row) {

      $id_tmp=$row->id_tmp;
      $codigo_producto=$row->codigo_producto;
      $cantidad=$row->cantidad_tmp;
      $nombre_producto=$row->nombre_producto;
      if (!empty($id_marca_producto))
      {
      $sql_marca=mysqli_query($con, "select nombre_marca from marcas where id_marca='$id_marca_producto'");
      $rw_marca=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_marca);
      $nombre_marca=$rw_marca['nombre_marca'];
      $marca_producto=" ".strtoupper($nombre_marca);
      }
      else {$marca_producto='';}
      $precio_venta=$row->precio_tmp;
      $precio_venta_f=number_format($precio_venta,2);//Formateo variables
      $precio_venta_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_venta_f);//Reemplazo las comas
      $precio_total=$precio_venta_r*$cantidad;
      $precio_total_f=number_format($precio_total,2);//Precio total formateado
      $precio_total_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_total_f);//Reemplazo las comas
      $sumador_total+=$precio_total_r;//Sumador
      
      echo'
        <tr>
          <td>'.$codigo_producto.'</td>
          <td>'.$cantidad.'</td>
          <td>'.$nombre_producto.$marca_producto.'</td>
          <td><span class="d-flex justify-content-end">'.$precio_venta_f.'</span></td>
          <td><span class="d-flex justify-content-end">'.$precio_total_f.'</span></td>
          <td ><span class="d-flex justify-content-end"><a href="#" id="eliminar"class="fa fa-trash" value="'.$id_tmp.'"></a></span></td>
        </tr> ';  
       
      }

    echo'
    <tr>
      <td colspan=4><span class="d-flex justify-content-end"><b>TOTAL</b> </span></td>
      <td><span class="d-flex justify-content-end"><b>'.number_format($sumador_total,2).'</b></span></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>';

      die(); // this is required to return a proper result
      
    }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

Todo este codigo se encarga de recibir de la tabla pedidos los datos, los procesa, los inserta en una tabla temporal, se hace una busqueda en esta tabla y se muestra en el resumen de pedido del fondo (donde se repiten las tablas)

```
 function agregar (id){
        
        var precio_venta = $('#precio_venta_'+id).val();
        var cantidad=$('#cantidad_'+id).val();
        //Inicia validacion
            if (isNaN(cantidad)) {
                alert('Esto no es un numero');
                document.getElementById('cantidad_'+id).focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (isNaN(precio_venta)) {
                alert('Esto no es un numero');
                document.getElementById('precio_venta_'+id).focus();
                return false;
            }
                //Fin validacion
            var parametros={"id":id,"precio_venta":precio_venta,"cantidad":cantidad};   
            
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var data = {
            dataType: "json",
            action: 'my_action',
            security : MyAjax.security,
            data: parametros
            };

            $.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {   
                //alert(response);      
                $('.prueba').append(response);
            });
        }); 
    };

    function eliminar (id) {
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            //var id = $('#eliminar_'+id).val();
            var data = {
                dataType: "json",
                action: 'my_action',
                security : MyAjax.security,
                data : id
            }   
            $.get(MyAjax.ajaxurl,data, function( response ) {
                $('.prueba').append(response);
                alert(response);
            })              
        });
    }
```

Este es mi código ajax, encargado de agregar los pedidos a la tabla resumen de pedidos, y tambien el ajax de eliminar pedidos, los echos del php anterior se envian en la respuesta ajax y se muestra en el div de la tabla donde se repiten...

```
        <?php

    function resumen_form($content) {
      echo'<div class="prueba"></div>';
    //}
    //add_shortcode('resumen_form', 'resumen_form');
      //check_ajax_referer( 'special-string', 'security' );

      $session_id = get_current_user_id();  
      
      $pedidos = $_POST['data'];

      if (isset($pedidos['id'])){
        $pedidos['id'];
      }
      if (isset($pedidos['cantidad'])){
        $pedidos['cantidad'];
      }
      if (isset($pedidos['precio_venta'])){
        $pedidos['precio_venta'];
      }
      
      if (!empty($id) and !empty($cantidad) and !empty($precio_venta)) { 
      $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'tmp', array('id_producto' => $pedidos['id'], 'cantidad_tmp' => $pedidos['cantidad'], 'precio_tmp' => $pedidos['precio_venta'],'session_id' => $session_id ));
      }
      
      if ( isset($_GET) ) {
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) { 
            $id_tmp = $_GET['data'];
            echo $id_temp;
            global $wpdb;     
            $wpdb->show_errors(); 
            $wpdb->delete( $wpdb->prefix.'tmp', array('id_tmp' => $id_tmp));
            
        }
        
      }
     

    echo'
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>codigo_producto</th>
      <th>cantidad</th>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th><span class="d-flex justify-content-end">Precio Unitario</span></th>
      <th><span class="d-flex justify-content-end">Precio Total</span></th>
      <th>Eliminar</th>
    </tr>';

      $sumador_total=0;

      global $wpdb;
      $wpdb->show_errors(); 
      $table_productos = $wpdb->prefix .'productos'; // nombre de la tabla 
      $table_tmp = $wpdb->prefix . 'tmp'; // nombre de la tabla 
      $prod = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_productos p, $table_tmp t where p.id_producto = t.id_producto and t.session_id='".$session_id."'");
      foreach ($prod as $row) {

      $id_tmp=$row->id_tmp;
      $codigo_producto=$row->codigo_producto;
      $cantidad=$row->cantidad_tmp;
      $nombre_producto=$row->nombre_producto;
      if (!empty($id_marca_producto))
      {
      $sql_marca=mysqli_query($con, "select nombre_marca from marcas where id_marca='$id_marca_producto'");
      $rw_marca=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_marca);
      $nombre_marca=$rw_marca['nombre_marca'];
      $marca_producto=" ".strtoupper($nombre_marca);
      }
      else {$marca_producto='';}
      $precio_venta=$row->precio_tmp;
      $precio_venta_f=number_format($precio_venta,2);//Formateo variables
      $precio_venta_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_venta_f);//Reemplazo las comas
      $precio_total=$precio_venta_r*$cantidad;
      $precio_total_f=number_format($precio_total,2);//Precio total formateado
      $precio_total_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_total_f);//Reemplazo las comas
      $sumador_total+=$precio_total_r;//Sumador
      
      ?>
      
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $codigo_producto;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $cantidad;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $nombre_producto.$marca_producto;?></td>
          <td><span class="d-flex justify-content-end"><?php echo $precio_venta_f;?></span></td>
          <td><span class="d-flex justify-content-end"><?php echo $precio_total_f;?></span></td>
          <td ><span class="d-flex justify-content-end"><a href="#" onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $id_tmp ?>')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></span></td>
        </tr>  
      <?php 
      }

    echo'
    <tr>
      <td colspan=4><span class="d-flex justify-content-end"><b>TOTAL</b> </span></td>
      <td><span class="d-flex justify-content-end"><b>'.number_format($sumador_total,2).'</b></span></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>';

    }
    add_shortcode('resumen_form', 'resumen_form');
```

Y esta es la tabla que muestra el resumen de pedidos...

Pueden ver al principio el  que me muestra la tabla completa que lo muestra el response del ajax traido del php anterior...

Disculpen lo largo del post, es un trabajo simple con codigo largo...

solo quiero que la tabla resumen agregue y elimine los productos en tiempo real arreglando este codigo que tengo...

P.D.: ya he googleado bastante para hacer todo eso, pero creanme, estoy agotado de seguir buscando y no conseguir respuesta para esto... he leido infinidades de cosas en 6 dias dedicados hasta tarde a esto.... y en verdad vine por ayuda para aligerar un poco la carga e ir directamente a una ayuda mas especifica...

De ante mano gracias al que se tome la molestia de ver este choricero y ayudarme.... se valora... exitos amigos...

Comment: Y dentro de todo esto.. donde es que esta tu problema?

Comment: solo quiero que la tabla resumen agregue y elimine los productos en tiempo real  y que no se repita la tabla completa cada vez que pulso agregar un producto... que el boton eliminar tambien elimine en tiempo real, en verdad es algo por hacer por partes, pero en resumidas todo el codigo trabaja en conjunto